# java.time not properly deserialised using jackson

Tags: java, scala, jackson, java-time, jsr310

Based on what's described [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime), I should be serialising `ZonedDateTime` object using the JSR-310 representation rather than the numeric one. However, I'm getting the numeric representation. What could be the problem?

This is how I configure the mapper I'm using:

```
object JsonFormatter {
  private val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper

  mapper
    .registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
    .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)

  def fromJson[T](json: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = mapper.readValue[T](json.getBytes)

  def toJson(value: Any): String = mapper.writeValueAsString(value)
}
```

This is an example of deserialisation I get

```
{"from":"CityA","to":"CityB","departureAt":1554970560.000000000,"arriveAt":1554984660.000000000,"duration":{"length":65,"unit":"MINUTES","finite":true}}
```

for the following case class:

```
case class Stock(from: String,
                 to: String,
                 departureAt: ZonedDateTime,
                 arriveAt: ZonedDateTime,
                 duration: Duration)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` feature is enabled by default so I had to disable it by adding:

```
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
```